How can i detect what folder in the Assets i selected?
instead Selection.objects like:
foreach (Object obj in Selection.objects)

i want to find the selected asset folder in the assets.  for example in editor script when i make right mouse click on a folder in the assets i want to get the folder name.
the full script:
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class CustomMenuItems
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Custom ReadMe File", false, 81)]
    private static void CreateReadMeFile()
    {
        // Get the selected folder path in the Project view
        string path = GetSelectedPathOrFallback();

        // Set the full path for the ReadMe.txt file
        string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "ReadMe.txt");

        // Check if the ReadMe file already exists in the selected folder
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // Write the content to the file
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, "This is a custom ReadMe file.\n\nYou can add your instructions here.");
            AssetDatabase.Refresh(); // Refresh the AssetDatabase to show the new file
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("ReadMe.txt already exists in the selected folder.");
        }
    }

    // Helper method to get the selected path or fall back to the root Assets folder
    private static string GetSelectedPathOrFallback()
    {
        string path = "Assets";

        // Check if there is a selected object in the Project view
        foreach (Object obj in Selection.objects)
        {
            // Get the asset path of the selected object
            string objPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj);

            // Check if the selected object is a folder
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPath) && Directory.Exists(objPath))
            {
                path = objPath;
                break;
            }
        }

        return path;
    }
}

i want it to create the readme file inside the folder where i did the right click mouse on it and not in the root Assets.

this is what i wanted :  string path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(Selection.assetGUIDs[0]);

this is working.  now i can create a readme text file in any folder in the assets i want. right click mouse in the assets:   Assts >  Create > Custom ReadMe File
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class CustomMenuItems
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Custom ReadMe File", false, 81)]
    private static void CreateReadMeFile()
    {
        // Get the selected folder path in the Project view
        string path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(Selection.assetGUIDs[0]);

        // Set the full path for the ReadMe.txt file
        string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "ReadMe.txt");

        // Check if the ReadMe file already exists in the selected folder
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // Write the content to the file
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, "This is a custom ReadMe file.\n\nYou can add your instructions here.");
            AssetDatabase.Refresh(); // Refresh the AssetDatabase to show the new file
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("ReadMe.txt already exists in the selected folder.");
        }
    }
}


You should use ˋPath.GetDirectoryˋ one it so it also works If you select an Asset instead of a folder ... In general also See https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-get-currently-selected-folder-for-putting-new-asset-into/439128
